How to prove that $X_n \stackrel{\text{a. s.}}{\rightarrow} 0$
Let $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly decreasing sequence of positive random variables such that $X_n \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} 0$. I have to prove that $X_n \stackrel{\text{a. s.}}{\rightarrow} 0$.
I know that $P\left(X_n > \varepsilon\right) \stackrel{n}{\rightarrow} 0$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ since the random variables are positive. I thought that if I show that $\sum\limits_{n} P\left(X_n > \varepsilon\right)$ converges then $X_n \stackrel{\text{a. s.}}{\rightarrow} 0$, but I don't know how to proceed.

For each $\omega$, $(X_n(\omega))_{n\ge0}$ is a (deterministic) decreasing sequence bounded from below by $0$, so it must converges to some number $X(\omega)\ge0$. This holds for all $\omega$ so you have $X_n\to X$ a.s. At the same time, $X_n\stackrel P\to 0$…

As $P(X_n>\varepsilon)\rightarrow 0$ there exists a subsequence $(X_{n_m}){m\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\sum{m} P(X_{n_m}>\varepsilon)$ converges. Then you get that $X_{n_m}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely. However, as $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing, we get $X_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely. Though neijmban's suggestion is way better.

@nejimban So $X_n \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} X$ and necessarily $X = 0$?

@CyclotomicManolo The limit for convergence in Probability is always unique.

@Mr.GandalfSauron That's it, it was so much easier than I was thinking. Thank you all!
